# Adding clicked items to new array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making API calls and rendering different components within an object. One of those is illustrated below:

```
class Bases extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            'basesObject': {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getBases();
    }

    getBases() {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/cupcakes/bases')
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(results => this.setState({'basesObject': results}))
    }

    render() {

        let {basesObject} = this.state;  
        let {bases} = basesObject; 

        console.log(bases); 
        //FALSY values: undefined, null, NaN, 0, false, ""

        return (

            <div>
                {bases && bases.map(item =>
                    <button key={item.key} className="boxes">
                        {/* <p>{item.key}</p> */}
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                        <p>${item.price}.00</p>
                        {/* <p>{item.ingredients}</p> */}
                    </button>
            )}
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The above renders a set of buttons. All my components look basically the same.

I render my components here:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    ordersArray: []
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bases</h1>
        <Bases />
        <h1>Frostings</h1>
        <Frostings />
        <h1>Toppings</h1>
        <Toppings />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to figure out the simplest way to, when a button is clicked by the user, add the key of each clicked element to a new array and I am not sure where to start. The user must select one of each, but is allowed to select as many toppings as they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try this

We can use the same component for all categories. All the data is handled by the parent (stateless component).

```
function Buttons({ list, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map(({ key, name, price, isSelected }) => (
        <button
          className={isSelected ? "active" : ""}
          key={key}
          onClick={() => handleClick(key)}
        >
          <span>{name}</span>
          <span>${price}</span>
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Fetch data in `App` component, pass the data and handleClick method into `Buttons`.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    basesArray: [],
    toppingsArray: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Get bases and toppings list, and add isSelected attribute with default value false
    this.setState({
      basesArray: [
        { key: "bases1", name: "bases1", price: 1, isSelected: false },
        { key: "bases2", name: "bases2", price: 2, isSelected: false },
        { key: "bases3", name: "bases3", price: 3, isSelected: false }
      ],
      toppingsArray: [
        { key: "topping1", name: "topping1", price: 1, isSelected: false },
        { key: "topping2", name: "topping2", price: 2, isSelected: false },
        { key: "topping3", name: "topping3", price: 3, isSelected: false }
      ]
    });
  }

  // for single selected category
  handleSingleSelected = type => key => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      [type]: state[type].map(item => ({
        ...item,
        isSelected: item.key === key
      }))
    }));
  };

  // for multiple selected category
  handleMultiSelected = type => key => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      [type]: state[type].map(item => {
        if (item.key === key) {
          return {
            ...item,
            isSelected: !item.isSelected
          };
        }
        return item;
      })
    }));
  };

  // get final selected item
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const { basesArray, toppingsArray } = this.state;
    const selectedBases = basesArray.filter(({ isSelected }) => isSelected);
    const selectedToppings = toppingsArray.filter(({ isSelected }) => isSelected);

    // submit the result here
  }

  render() {
    const { basesArray, toppingsArray } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bases</h1>
        <Buttons
          list={basesArray}
          handleClick={this.handleSingleSelected("basesArray")}
        />
        <h1>Toppings</h1>
        <Buttons
          list={toppingsArray}
          handleClick={this.handleMultiSelected("toppingsArray")}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

CSS

```
button {
  margin: 5px;
}
button.active {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: This almost works for me but I cant get the buttons to stay clicked like yours. To confirm, did you place the Buttons function at the top of the App.js file?

Comment: Also this doesn't add the items into a new array. Im mostly confused on that part.

Comment: @CoryAllen did you place the Buttons function at the top of the App.js file -> Yes.

Comment: this doesn't add the items into a new array -> it will update the isSelected attribute at the original list, so just filter the list to get the selected items. I add this part into my answer for reference.

Comment: can you post the css style you used too?

Comment: @CoryAllen add CSS to the answer, But it's just browser default + limited adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following example would be a good start for your case.

Define a `handleClick` function where you can set state with `setState` as the following:

```
handleClick(item) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
       ...prevState,
       clickedItems: [...prevState.clickedItems, item.key]
    };
  });
}
```

Create an array called `clickedItems` in constructor for `state` and bind `handleClick`:

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
      basesObject: {},
      clickedItems: [],
   }

   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

You need to add a `onClick={() => handleClick(item)}` handler for `onClick`:

```
<button key={item.key} className="boxes" onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>
   {/* <p>{item.key}</p> */}
   <p>{item.name}</p>
   <p>${item.price}.00</p>
   {/* <p>{item.ingredients}</p> */}
</button>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This looks great, but what if I dont want to repeat myself? Is there any way I could do the handleClick function inside the App Component and call it on all my other components?

Comment: You have a bug:  If you write `{...prevState, newClickedItems}` it will rename `clickedItems` to `newClickedItems`  Instead write: `{ ...prevState, clickedItems: [...prevState.clickedItems, item.key] }`

Comment: @CoryAllen I guess then you need to create the state array in `App` level and pass down the click event through `props` to `Bases` component. So technically you are pushing from child component into parent component's array. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that would look like.

Comment: It's not the bases I need added. I need 1 base, 1 frosting, and unlimited toppings. Those are the elements that need to go into the array.